# PHP: Redirect 404 errors below specific folder

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am working on a already existing intranet. I have build an application and would like to take care of the 404 errors.
The problem I have is that this error management should only have effects on the pages located below the folder I'm working on.

Explications:
My file explorer looks like this:

- root

  - aFolder

    - anotherFolder

      - RootOfMyApplication

        - myPages

I want to redirect all 404 errors **below RootOfMyApplication** to a specific page using PHP.
For example, browsing to "..../anotherFolder/RootOfMyApplication/notExist.php " should redirect me to my custom page, but browsing to "..../anotherFolder/notExist.php " should'nt.

If possible, I would like to make it so that directory browsing follow the same rule: if the url links to a folder and is below RootOfMyApplication, I redirect to the page.

The problem comes from the fact that I don't manage the root directory, and if possible want to have no impact on navigation outside my folder.

### EDIT

What I want to do is the same as a .htaccess file: when an error is thrown, I want to take care of it myself, with PHP. My question is : "Can I do it, and if yes, how do I do it?". I don't want to use configuration files.
"It's not possible" will be accepted as an answer if there is a good explanation.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565628/redirecting-to-homepage-rather-than-404-error-page?rq=1

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: I am using Apache2, but what I want to do is to set the redirection with PHP. I don't know if it's possible tho. 
I re-added PHP tag and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error Handling of files which are not found is a job of the Webserver (in your case Apache).
PHP can't help you because you always have to request one file which is then executed by PHP.

If you are going to request a file which doesn't exist, it can't be executed and the Webserver has do deal with the error. (PHP won't be started.)

But maybe there is a workaround:

1. If you use URL-Rewriting on your server/ application, there could be a way, but we would need some more Information/ code.
2. Can't you create an .htaccess in your root directory and change the error documents for your folder?
3. Talk to the admin and tell him he should change the error documents for your folder in httpd.conf.

(2./ 3. Maybe not an allowed solution for you, because you don't want do use configurations files.)

Comment: 2/3 are indeed not applicable in root folder.  
But can I set an .htaccess file in my subfolder to be used only there?
I mean, I can set it up in the root of my applucation, but not in the server root.

Comment: It is up to the server configuration, just try it. And an admin can always do it just for your folder.